# How do you call systems in which the more you have, the more you make?

Tags: definition

I am looking for a term for systems or dynamics in which the ability to earn a particular resource requires having a minimum of that resource available, and grows progressively or exponentially with it. I want to do some research on “you need money to make money” situations, but applied to non economic contexts as well.

I have zero background in economics, so apologies if I’m not using the proper tag (had no idea which to even use) or terms.

Comment: Not sure, but this may be better for [English.SE]. Seems like your interest is not purely in economics, otherwise "money" would be an okay answer.

Comment: Thanks Giskard. I considered posting it there, but I imagined there’s probably a specialised term for this in economics, even if it’s too broad.

Comment: What do you mean by system? There are mathematical models that can model such behavior and more complex ones can be called systems. If you mean something more broad like system of economic organization like for example free market, central planning etc then I don’t think that there are any systems like that. If you look for some examples then like the previous comment suggested money with compound interest would be an example of something that can increase exponentially